# HTML.DropDownList Default Value save as NULL and still work on selected values

Tags: xml, null, html-select, selectedvalue

I have a value in the DB that can be NULL and is causing me problems with Html.DropDownList.  The code is stored in the DB, and is currently setting the selected value correctly.

```
<%= Html.DropDownList("dealerIds"
                                , new List<SelectListItem>(((List<Company.SPPC.MVC.DealerId>)ViewData["dealerIds"]).Select(i => new SelectListItem() { Value = i.Key, Text = i.Description }).ToList())
                                , new { tabloop = "", id = "ddlDealerIds" })%>
```

In the controller, I pull the values from an XML file and add them to the ViewData:

```
Dim dealerIdXmlFile As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("DealerIdXmlFile").ToString()
        Using reader As System.IO.FileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(dealerIdXmlFile)
            Dim xmlSerializer As New System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(GetType(DealerIdModel))
            Dim dealerIdList As DealerIdModel = xmlSerializer.Deserialize(reader)
            Dim dealerIds As New List(Of DealerId)
            For Each x As DealerId In dealerIdList
                dealerIds.Add(x)
            Next
            ViewData("dealerIds") = dealerIds
        End Using
```

Also, the binding is explicitly set in the View:

```
$("#ddlDealerIds").attr("data-bind", "value: DealerId");
```

The issues is in two parts:

(1.) I want to add a "No ID Selected" that is the default value and will store as a NULL.  I was able to get a default value in the list by adding it to the HTML.DropDownList (..., "No ID Selected"), but when I do this, the selected value is always the default, even if the record has a valid code.

I could also add it to my XML list, but then the NULL value is not matching with the XML record:

```
DealerId key = "" Desc="No ID Selected" ....
```

Also, if I view a record with valid ID, then pull up one that is NULL, the drop down stays selected to the old valid ID.

(2.)  Even if adding a default value, I still want the dropdownlist to get the selected value set if there is a valid code in the DB.

I have looked at a few other posts on here, and while this seems to be common, I can't make heads or tails out of any of the solutions posted.  If I add the default value, I am not getting a selected value set ever.  If I fix to set the selected value, NULL values are not getting set to the default but keep the last selected DealerId value in the dropdown.

Comment: I did some following testing and found this doesn't error...so what is this first argument then? I thought it was the object that set the selected value? `<%= Html.DropDownList("SomethingThatDoesntExist", new List<SelectListItem>(((List<Company.SPPC.....`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it to work by getting ride of the HTMLHelpers and using Knockout.JS.  Set the options and everything works.

```
<div class="editor-field"><select id="ddlDealerIds" data-bind="options: dealerIdsList, optionsText: 'Description', optionsValue: 'Key', optionsCaption: '*** No Id Selected ***', value: DealerId"></select></div>
```